# Upsert INVALID_FIELD

Tags: api, custom-object, c#

I have a custom object which is a child object of Account.  Account has an external ID field called Customer_ID__c.  I have the following C# code which worked fine as a regular "create" when I was just inserting fields and not worrying about lookup fields.

```
            ChurchHist__c[] ChurchHist = new ChurchHist__c[endRecord - startRecord + 1];
            Account[] parentAccountRef = new Account[endRecord - startRecord + 1];
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", startRecord, endRecord);
            sObject[] s = new sObject[endRecord - startRecord + 1];

            for (int i = startRecord; i <= endRecord; i++)
            {                  
                DataRow dr = table.Rows[i];
                int rec = i - startRecord;

                ChurchHist[rec] = new ChurchHist__c();
                ChurchHist[rec].ChurchId__c = dr["ChurchId"].ToString();                    
                ChurchHist[rec].ChurchName__c = dr["ChurchName"].ToString();
                ChurchHist[rec].ReportYear__c = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ReportYear"]);
                ChurchHist[rec].ReportYear__cSpecified = true;
                ChurchHist[rec].ReportMonth__c = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ReportMonth"]);
                ChurchHist[rec].ReportMonth__cSpecified = true;
                ChurchHist[rec].RegisteredMembers__c = Convert.ToInt32(dr["RegisteredMembers"]);
                ChurchHist[rec].RegisteredMembers__cSpecified = true;
                ChurchHist[rec].ActiveMembers__c = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ActiveMembers"]);
                ChurchHist[rec].ActiveMembers__cSpecified = true;
                ChurchHist[rec].InactiveMembers__c = Convert.ToInt32(dr["InactiveMembers"]);
                ChurchHist[rec].InactiveMembers__cSpecified = true;
                ChurchHist[rec].UsersForMonth__c = Convert.ToInt32(dr["UsersForMonth"]);
                ChurchHist[rec].UsersForMonth__cSpecified = true;
                ChurchHist[rec].ContribForMonth__c = Convert.ToDouble(dr["ContribForMonth"]);
                ChurchHist[rec].ContribForMonth__cSpecified = true;
                ChurchHist[rec].ContribYTD__c = Convert.ToDouble(dr["ContribYTD"]);
                ChurchHist[rec].ContribYTD__cSpecified = true;
                ChurchHist[rec].AchContrib__c = Convert.ToDouble(dr["AchContrib"]);
                ChurchHist[rec].AchContrib__cSpecified = true;
                ChurchHist[rec].CcContrib__c = Convert.ToDouble(dr["CcContrib"]);
                ChurchHist[rec].CcContrib__cSpecified = true;
                ChurchHist[rec].AchToCc__c = Convert.ToDouble(dr["AchToCc"]);
                ChurchHist[rec].AchToCc__cSpecified = true;
                DateTime eom = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["EndOfMonth"]);
                ChurchHist[rec].EndOfMonth__c = eom;
                ChurchHist[rec].EndOfMonth__cSpecified = true;
                ChurchHist[rec].MonthName__c = eom.ToString(@"MMM \'yy");


                // NEW for UPSERT
                parentAccountRef[rec] = new Account();
                parentAccountRef[rec].Customer_ID__c = dr["ChurchId"].ToString();
                ChurchHist[rec].AcctLookup__r = parentAccountRef[rec];

                s[rec] = ChurchHist[rec];
            }
            try
            {
                UpsertResult[] results = _sfConn.upsert("Customer_ID__c", s);
            }
            catch (SoapException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());                    
            }
```

I am getting error

> INVALID_FIELD: Field name provided, AcctLookup__c does not match an
>   External ID, Salesforce Id, or indexed field for ChurchHist__c.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Last idea, I promise, before I'll try out the integration code myself. Simply put `_sfConn.upsert("Id", s);`. I think it's a mandatory parameter for upsert but as you don't care about finding existing ChurchHist records - Id can be blank and it'll reduce to blind insert + match Account by ext.id.

Comment: Using Id did the trick!  I don't even see an Id field listed in the Schema, must be one of those hidden SF things?  LOL

Comment: We had same on the chat when Data Loader didn't like the input CSV until you cleared the values from Id column (but the column had to be present), that's why I asked you to play with DL first, get a good feeling of the process. Eh. Small things, as always ;)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like what you're trying to do is resolve the FK to account, rather than upsert your ChurchHist__c record itself, in which case you don't need to use upsert. The ability to resolve foreign keys by using the related objects external id works in create, update & upsert calls, you don't need to specicially call upsert. You seem to be setting up the FK reference ok,so you can just change your code to call create instead of upsert and you should be all set.

Comment: Holy sheet, it's awesome news. I thought only upsert offers it because that's the only place in Data Loader flow where option to resolve them pops up. Means I've sent Randy down the rabbit hole with upserts for no good reason :/

Comment: It's always good to learn new stuff :) Yesterday was the first day I've really had to work on the ChurchHist thing that @eyescream guided me though setting up before Christmas. Got stuck making some changes to an internal web app. :(   Now back to Salesforce.  But I still would have needed to set the relationship with the 3 lines under the comment "NEW for UPSERT" ?  And Create would have still made everything work?

Comment: Yes, set the relationship up as you have it, just change the upsert call to a create call and you should be all done.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Customer_Id__c is checked as an External ID field (Setup > Create > Objects > ChuchHist > Customer_Id__c (Edit).

Comment: the FK field doesn't need to be an externalId to have its FK resolved from a related objects externalId.

Comment: Well it fixed my problem ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your external field, `Customer_ID__c` is on the Account, not ChurchHist__c. Your code would work for upserting Accounts, but that isn't the object you're working on. You either need to mark ChurchHist__c.Customer_ID__c as an external id or change the field being used in your upsert to one that is an external id.

** Update **

Based on @eyescream's comment, maybe your upsert field should be `AcctLookup__r.Customer_Id__c`?

Comment: Not really (it's a follow up of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20573980). The goal is to upsert by ext. id of Account. I think it should be `_sfConn.upsert("Account.Customer_ID__c", s);` or something like that

Comment: I didn't know you could upsert like that; I thought the field must be on the object itself.

Comment: Tried both of the above "AcctLookup_r.Customer_ID__c" and "Account.Customer_ID__c" and get the same error with both.